# Does ubuntu 14.04 still have desktop web app integration?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

I remember a while back I could integrate web apps into ubuntu.  This doesn't seem possible anymore.

Chrome or firefox do not prompt me anymore (perhaps I said no to this prompt once?) and I can't find anything about it on google.

It seems there used to be a separate app called unitywebapps or something similar.

Is this still a thing?  If so, how can I get it?

Using ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it does, but I believe they are off by default now, you can enable the prompts by using `unity-tweak-tool`

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

[image]

Also you can find all `webapps` in the `software center`

[image]

Comment: If this helped you please click the check mark on the left to say thanks and let others easily find the correct answer.

Comment: ah, was wondering how to do that as it wouldn't let me vote up or down yet.  Thanks for that, too!